# Does 'right speech' prohibit expressions which "hate" anything at all?

Tags: right-speech

Does 'right speech' prohibit expressions which "hate" anything at all?

So, not an individual, or even really a point of view, but to ex-press the sensation of intense (if not actually visceral) *dislike*?

Answer (score 2):

Here on Access to Insight there's a anthology of descriptions of right speech speech from the Pali suttas: [Right Speech *samma vaca*](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-vaca/)

IMO something like, "It is spoken with a mind of good-will", or "speaks words that are soothing to the ear, that are affectionate, that go to the heart, that are polite, appealing & pleasing to people at large", might be quite incompatible with "express the sensation of intense (if not actually visceral) dislike".

I think the Buddha as portrayed in the suttas might point out that an action or view was "unskillful", or "leads to suffering" ... but *wouldn't* say something like, "I hate that".

But see also [What is a wrathful Buddha?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10694/254) (from another tradition, Tibetan Buddhism) about maybe appearing to be angry.

See also this question, [Did the Buddha ever 'thunder' during a Fire Sermon?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4117/254), in which I asked whether the Buddha would "display affect". The accepted answer says, "The closest he gets to actual disturbance is ... Pretty tame, but then that's to be expected; he was, after all, a fully enlightened Buddha."

Also, "hate" is usually seen as one of the fundamental "[three poisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_poisons)" (with possibly some difference between Theravada and Mahayana viewpoints e.g. as might be inferred from this topic, [Could Lobha(craving) and Dosa(aversion) be working in tandem?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4057/254)) -- see also the fact that [equanimity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upekkha) is a virtue: it's presumably better to abandon even the experience of hate, let alone the expression of hate.

Comment: good ending, and synposis